# Toggling High contrast in windows causes C# WPF to trigger loaded and unloaded events

Tags: c#, wpf

Like the title said, my C# .NET framework app loaded and unloaded events are triggered by high contrast settings in windows.

Are there any ways to prevent loaded and unloaded from triggering when the high contrast setting in windows are changed?

I am fine even if the visual maintains at the none high contrast settings even if I turn the high contrast on in windows settings.